# How to check if a given post belongs to a given user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Given I have

```
$user = User::where('name','Craig')->first();

$post = Post::first();
```

I want to check if the above `$post` belongs to `$user` in a nice Laravel way.

Something like

```
$exists = $user->posts()->contains($post->id);
```

But that does not work as it is a many to one relationship.

Comment: Surely this would already be posing as a problem if you're referring back to the users name? What if there are 15 Craigs... Why not assign each post to a userid instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
$exists = $user->posts->contains('id', $post->id)
```

Comment: This will actually pull all of the user's posts from the DB into your app's memory. There's no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$belongs = $post->user_id == $user->id;
```